# Question about the orientation of UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have two viewController, A and B.

I want that this app is just for Landscape, so in A and B I overwrite

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

There are two ways to init B, and add B's view as a subview of A

1.

In A's viewDidLoad, I get the object of B through init method.

```
B *bController = [[B alloc] init];
b.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview:b.view];
```

2.

In A's viewDidLoad, I get the object of B through initWithNib method.
In B's Nib file. I change the orientation of view to LandScape, and change the size of view to (480,300)

When I output the frame of B's view in B's viewDidLoad method, I got different result.

The output of "**method 1**" is (320,460), although the device was rotated to Landscape and view was full of screen.

The output of "**method2**" is (480,300).This is just for my expectation.

Why the output of method1 isnt (480,300) but (320,460)?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just set the supported orientations of the project to Landscape only?  In Xcode 4 click on the project file, go to Summary, and look at Supported Device Orientations.  Click on the Portrait modes to disable them.

Comment: You should have just one view controller in charge of an entire view hierarchy. In other words, you shouldn't be adding B's view as a subview of A's view. Container controllers like UINavigationController are an obvious exception, but those don't have views of their own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the autoSizing property of subView, that's it.